# GEE ee.Image.sample javascript to python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to convert the following javascript to python:

```
var f = final.sample({region: county_j,
    scale: scale,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    numPixels: numPixels});
```

The problem is how to translate the sample function, my python code is:

```
f = final.sample({region: county_j,
    scale: scale,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    numPixels: numPixels})
```

But it faces an error:

```
ee.ee_exception.EException: Invalid GeoJSON geometry.
```

Could you tell me how to write the sample function in python?

Comment: I find an example at Line 25-26. https://github.com/google/earthengine-community/blob/6801dd2d05d1cd6a44d8c86131accda657c253ce/samples/python/apidocs/ee_featurecollection_copyproperties.py
The python api can be written as javascript api and only add '**' before the {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly don't know how your shapefile looks like or what columns it has, is it a point, line or polygon but I believe you're reading the shapefile using Geopandas and then trying to use the sample function? If that's the case here's how the Python syntax should look like:

```
scale = 1000  # define a scale in meters
f = final.sample(county_j, scale)
```

You can find more information on Python API from this [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api).

Comment: I find an example at Line 25-26 in https://github.com/google/earthengine-community/blob/6801dd2d05d1cd6a44d8c86131accda657c253ce/samples/python/apidocs/ee_featurecollection_copyproperties.py
The python api can be written as javascript api and only add '**' before the {}.

Comment: Yes the '**' used at the front is used to unpack the values in a dictionary in Python.